# How to differentiate account types in Django?

Tags: python, django

Thanks in advance if you're reading this... I'm a High School student working on a web application using Django, to help students find internships, and facilitate parents posting internship offers -- a sort of marketplace if you will.

I'm trying to create a profile/account page for the users but I need a way to differentiate between whether the account logged in is a Student or Employer so that I can use views.py to generate a page appropriate to their account.

In models.py, I have two different profile types which can be associated with a user account (handled by django.contrib.auth), see below for reference.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profilePic = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Student Profile'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}'s Profile"


class Employer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profilePic = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Unspecified')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Employer/Parent Profile'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}'s Profile"
```

In my views.py page, I'm trying to create a view for the account/profile that can detect whether the currently logged-in user's profile is linked to either the 'Student' or 'Parent' model and serve a page accordingly. I've tried a very rudimentary approach, as below, but unsurprisingly it's not working.

```
def account(request):
    if user.student.username == True:
        context = 'Account: Student'
        return render(request, 'users/studentprofile.html', context)

    elif user.employer.username == True:
        context = 'Account: Employer'
        return render(request, 'users/employer.html', context)
```

I was wondering if anyone had a suggestion as to how I can best accomplish this... apologies in advance is this approach is poorly structured or against the status-quo of Django Programming, I'm a complete beginner!

Thanks in advance all :)

Answer (score 2):

You can actually check if the user has a `student` or `employer` attribute by using [hasattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr)

```
if hasattr(user, 'student'):
    ... # your logic

elif hasattr(user, 'employer'):
    ... # your logic
```

The following is completely optional, but what I personally like to do is to create some simple functions on my user model like in this example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...

    def is_student(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'student')

    def is_employer(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'employer')
```

And then, you can use those in the view:

```
if user.is_student():
    ... # your logic

elif user.is_employer():
    ... # your logic
```

By the way, do not apologize for being a beginner! This is a good question. I would suggest you to read the docs on [One-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships).

Hope it helps!